# jQuery Weekcalendar Some methods don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have some HTML markup and I have a `<div id=calendar>...<div>` in it

I'm using the `<div id=calendar>...<div>` as a jQuery ui dialog box and inside this tag, I have a jQuery week calendar. But when I open the dialog that contains the week calendar, some of it's methods don't work.

For example I have set the `_scrollToHour(10)` but it doesn't scroll to 10. During all of this, the Javascript console in browser does not show any errors.

When I use this jQuery week calendar outside a jQuery ui dialog, it works properly.

Can anybody tell me how I can use the jQuery week calendar inside a jQuery ui dialog ?

Comment: Could you add some example code please? Maybe using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or another online demo site

Answer (score 1):

Did u try attaching the event handlers using .live() ?

[Jquery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: can u explain more about jQuery Live please ?